# How does the Java compiler work when you have a class `c` inside itself?

Tags: java, compilation

Consider the following code

```
public class myClass{
    myClass instanceOfNotYetDefinedClass;
    ... //etc code
}
```

I don't understand how the compiler manages to understand that: I'm telling it to create a class, and then it says: "OK! Let me see what this myClass class has. Oh, its a myClass, let me see whats this has..." etc.

It may be a pretty noobish question, but  I really don't understand how this could be handled.

Comment: Java is OpenSource, look at the sourcecode. ;-)

Comment: Compilers don't talk to themselves like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that a compiler can do this:

Approach #1: Make two passes over the parse tree:

- In pass 1, find all declarations and all scope boundaries, and populate a symbol table<sup>1</sup>.
- In pass 2, find all identifier references and resolve them against the symbol table.

Approach #2: Make a single pass over the parse tree:

- Create a symbol table entry whenever a declaration is encountered
- When an identifier reference is encountered:

  1. try to resolve it in the symbol table
  2. if the resolution fails, add it to a list to be resolved later
- At the end of the pass, revisit all identifiers in the list and attempt to resolve them again against the (now complete) symbol table.

And there are variations, and possibly other approaches.

But if you really want to know how the Java compiler *actually* does it, look at the OpenJDK source code.

---

A reference to a class in itself is actually simpler.  In your example code, the compiler will "see" the parse tree node for `public class myClass` before it sees the use of `myClass`.  So when it encounters the latter, the entry for `myClass` will already be in the symbol table.

---

(In old fashioned language like C, the declaration and definition of a function can be separate, but you can refer to an identifier if it has been declared earlier in the compilation unit.)

---

<sup>1 - If you don't know what a symbol table is, there are good text books on compilers and compiler construction.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To see what the compiler does, compile the class with javac and run javap on it. Doing this with your class gives the following:

```
public class myClass {
    myClass instanceOfNotYetDefinedClass;
    public myClass();
}
```

The `public myClass();` is a default constructor and is irrelevant here. From this, we can see that the compiler just attaches a field of type `myClass` to `myClass`. How does this work? As `myClass` is an existing class in the code's scope, the compiler knows it will be defined at runtime. It therefore simply leaves this definition as it is. At runtime, calling `myClass.instanceOfNotYetDefinedClass` gives you the field's value - which is either `null` if you don't initialise it, or a `myClass` instance which has its own field. There is no infinite recursion or conflict here, unless you make it happen e.g. calling `new myClass()` in the constructor.